# Start-Process doesn't work in powershell remoting

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I've been trying to to run calculator using powershell remoting. I entered a powershell session (with `Enter-PSSession`), and entered the following command:

```
Start-Process calc.exe
```

I looked at the remote computer and nothing showed up. When I try other commands like `Get-Process` or `Stop-Process` they work fine. I looked online and saw womewhere that I should try using `-PassThrough` to see if it's doing anything and I got this result:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
      7       4     1228       2388    35     0.02    528 calc
```

So I decided to look in task manager on the computer I was connecting to to see if the process is running, but it wasn't there. Only when I clicked "Show processes from all users" it showed up, even though the user listed on the process was the one I was logged in to. I tried using some other windows programs like mspaint and notepad and got the same results.

Does anyone know why this is happening? The processes seem to run without opening the gui.

EDIT: I just noticed that the process is stopped once the session is closed. Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a session with `enter-pssession`, it is its own "entity" - you cannot connect it to an interactive desktop session, nor is there any GUI for the application(s) you start to interact with. It's an interactive text-based console only, and even if you're logged into the console as well, it's two separate user sessions and they cannot communicate.

So even though you can start a process that has a GUI, there is no GUI for it to attach to or display on.

Comment: Is there no way to get around this?

Comment: Not with PowerShell Remoting, that's just how it works. You can use [psexec to do it](http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-i-to-interact-w-desktop_topic2940.html), but it's failing for me at the moment.