# Send pop up with options to remote PC

Tags: powershell, popup

I would like to send popup window to users (I'm admin so I have the rights to their computers) in my network but with buttons so they click it and it will trigger an action. To make an example I've got this code:

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Support\test.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $msgBoxInput = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Would you like to play a game?', 'Game  input', 'YesNoCancel', 'Error') -ComputerName $computer

    switch ($msgBoxInput) {
        'Yes' {
            ## Do something 
        }
        'No' {
            ## Do something
        }
        'Cancel' {
            ## Do something
        }
    }
}
```

The popup window itself is working but it will display only on my computer not on remote PC which is listed in the .txt file so the problem is with the part computer name `-ComputerName $computer`.

Does anyone has an idea how to do it?

Comment: what is the format of your string in the test.txt file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start-Process doesn't work in powershell remoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135319/start-process-doesnt-work-in-powershell-remoting)

Comment: Messagebox Show is a .Net framework library call, it is not a PowerShell cmdlet, it doesn't take a computername parameter. You would need to use Invoke-Command to run your  code on a remote computer with remoting, but Windows doesn't let you connect in and show things on the GUI easily, you need to use a workaround like using PSExec or configuring a scheduled task, and then you won't be able to get the result back easily..

Comment: only plain text computer name nothing special ... just: localpc1 etc.

Comment: Usually for something like this to work you need a server process running in the user's context on the remote host, and a client process running on your host. Your client connects to the server process and sends the information you want displayed, and the server process does the actual displaying.